# POX programming and hello packet

Tags: sdn, pox

I'm new with SDN and I want to write Python code to create switch and three hosts and controller also send hello packet from the switch to the controller

Comment: It's good for you! Seriously, what is your question? Please specify exact problem you have and what is a desired result.

Comment: I want to write python code to connect switch to controller then send hello message to the controller and display all packets go through the controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mininet to create switches and use Pox as a controller.
Once you create a network topology in Mininet, you can run POX connecting switches in Mininet and switches will send Hello message to Pox automatically.

Here is the Mininet website: http://mininet.org